# Git: how to melt a commit to another commit?

Tags: git

Let's say I have git commit history like this(newer -> older):

C -> B -> A

after C's commit, I came to realize that there is something wrong with A.Maybe a test case which is suppose to be in that commit,but actually it wasn't there. So how can I deal with this situation? Make a new commit and melt it into A?how?

Problem solved:

1. `git checkout A`
2. `git checkout -b fix`
3. edit
4. `git add files`
5. `git commit --amend`
6. `git rebase fix master`

Comment: You could branch from A, make your commit, and then rebase B+C on top of it.

Comment: make a new commit D that fixes the problem inside A in a new branch. Then do `git rebase --interactive`. This will allow you to re-order the commits you made (sort it so that it is C->B->D->A). Be careful: this is rewriting the commit history and you will run into problems if other people already pulled you branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of persons will said to you to do `rebase --interactive` (which could be the solution) but if you plan to change some lines that had been changed in commits B or C, that will be a hell to use.

The another solution could be :

1. Create and checkout a branch on commit A
2. Amend the commit A or create a new commit (depend on what sense you give to what you want to do)
3. Checkout the previous branch which is still on commit C
4. Use `rebase --onto` to rebase only commit B and C on the newly created branch (that you could delete after)